# Как изменить цвет autocomplete в sublime text 3?

Tags: sublime-text

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Какое свойство отвечает за цвет вот этой менюшки и где оно находится?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За цвет бэкграунда всплывающих подсказок в Sublime Text 3 отвечает класс `table_row`.

<kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Browse Paskages</kbd> → <kbd>User</kbd>, создаём файл ***Default.sublime-theme***, если он ещё не создан, и между `[]` вставляем в него следующий код:

```
// Бэкграунд всплывающих подсказок
    {
        "class": "table_row",
        "layer1.tint": [255, 228, 225, 255],
        "layer1.opacity": 1,
    },
```

Где `layer1.tint` — цвет бэкграунда всплывающих подсказок в [RGBA](http://cuprum.name/page/cvetovaya-model-rgba), `layer1.opacity` — прозрачность бэкграунда, свойство принимает значения от 0 до 1.

[image: Всплывающая подсказка в Sublime Text 3]

За текст всплывающих подсказок отвечает класс `auto_complete_label`:

```
// Текст в автокомплите
    {
        "class": "auto_complete_label",
        "fg": [72, 72, 72, 255],
        "match_fg": [0, 0, 0, 255],
        "selected_fg": [250, 128, 114, 255],
        "selected_match_fg": [220, 20, 60, 255]
    },
```

[image: Текст всплывающих подсказок]

- `fg` — цвет текста невыделенных вариантов автокомплита,
- `match_fg` — цвет уже набранного текста в невыделенных вариантах,
- `selected_fg` — цвет текста выделенных вариантов автокомплита (когда появляются варианты автозаполнения, их можно выбирать стрелками вверх/вниз),
- `selected_match_fg` — цвет уже набранного текста в выделенных вариантах.